# Azure Resource Manager template in Visual Studio for Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

When you create a new Azure Service Fabric solution in Visual Studio, when built and run, you can navigate to the fabric explorer, and in the Manifest tab, it shows the script generated. This looks to me like an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template.

To enable reverse proxy in my service fabric application, I need to modify this ARM template, or create a new one based on a sample template, and then bring that into Visual Studio somehow. Basically I'm looking for assistance to find where that connection is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cluster manifest the you see in Service Fabric Explorer is not the ARM template, but you change the manifest through ARM, if running Service Fabric in Azure.

To enable the reverse proxy in ARM see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#setup-and-configuration

To get the current ARM template for your cluster deployment, go to the Azure Portal and download the template to VS: [How can I download template json for an Azure Resource Group that I created in the portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966235/how-can-i-download-template-json-for-an-azure-resource-group-that-i-created-in-t/36270305#36270305)

Finally update the deployment from PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm#create-the-cluster